# DateTimeField object has no attribute strftime

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls

My main code is this:

```
  class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    publishdate = created_on.strftime('%Y/%m')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

When I run this code, I get:

```
'DateTimeField' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

referring to publishdate

strftime works with datetime.datetime, and DateTimeField converts to datetime.datetime, so what am I doing wrong?

I've tried to convert to datetime.datetime to no avail

EDIT: Having seen answers, I think I should verify what I'm trying to do

I'm trying to add the date to this url in urls.py:

```
   urlpatterns = [
      path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
      path('<publishdate>/<slug:slug>', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'
]
```

EDIT 2: I've updated my code to this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    created_on_string = created_on.value_to_string(created_on)
    publishdate = strptime(created_on_string, '%Y/%m')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and the output is:

```
File "C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 933, in value_from_object
    return getattr(obj, self.attname)
AttributeError: 'DateTimeField' object has no attribute 'attname'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the class level, `created_on` is a `DateTimeField`, not the `datetime` object a `Post` *object* (not the class) holds. If you want to add a property that formats it, you can use:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # …
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def publishdate(self):
        return self.created_on.strftime('%Y/%m')

    # …
```

That being said, formatting data is usually *not* the task of a model. A model is used to *store* and *represent* data. In a template you can for example use the [**`|date`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) to format a `datetime` object in a specified format. For a given `Post` object `post`, you for example can format this as:

```
{{ post.created_on|date:'Y/m' }}
```

For the URL, you can use two parameters:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path(
        '<int:year>/<int:month>/<slug:slug>',
        views.PostDetail.as_view(),
        name='post_detail'
    )
]
```

in your view you then filter with:

```
class PostDetail(DetailView):
    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            created_on__year=self.kwargs['year'],
            created_on__month=self.kwargs['month']
        )
```

In a template, you can then link to the view with a `post` object with:

```
{% url 'post_detail' post.created_on.year post.created_on.month post.slug %}
```

Comment: After reading this, I thought I should clarify my question. Please see my edits

Comment: @Aknell: but this is again not the responsibility of a model. Django uses a model-view-modelview architecture. Please try to keep this layers "clean".

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it work by adding a `self` to the attribute at the class level?

```py
publishdate = self.created_on.strftime('%Y/%m')
```

Comment: Tried that. Didn't fix it